# PHP isset function is not checking properly

Tags: php, html, post, isset

When the button is clicked. I want to get the values from the form using the register_button. However, it does not get inside the if clause.

I can not check anything typed at the form within the if statement.
Is there any other options that I can retrieve data from the form with or am I doing some mistake?

`var_dump($_POST)` returns

```
array(6) { 
    ["reg_fname"]=> string(1) "a" 
    ["reg_lname"]=> string(3) "asd" 
    ["reg_email"]=> string(5) "ad@ad" 
    ["reg_pass"]=> string(4) "dasd" 
    ["reg_pass2"]=> string(5) "sadsa" 
    ["register_button"]=> string(8) "Register" 

} 

Invalid format
```

Code:

```
$fname = "";
$lname = "";
$em = "";
$em2 = "";
$password = "";
$password2 = "";
$date = "";
$error_array = "";

if (isset($_POST['register_button'])) {

    $fname = strip_tags($_POST['reg_fname']);
    $fname = str_replace(' ', ' ', $fname);
    $lname = $_POST['reg_lname'];
    $lname = str_replace(' ', ' ', $lname);

    $em = $_POST['reg_email'];
    $em = str_replace(' ', ' ', $em);

    $password = strip_tags($_POST['reg_pass']);
    $password2 = strip_tags($_POST['reg_pass2']);

    $date = date("Y-m-d");

    if(filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $em = filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

        $e_check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em");

        $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($e_check);

        if(num_rows > 0){
            echo "Email already in use";
        }
    }else {
        echo "Invalid format";
    }

    if(strlen(fname)>25 || strlen(fname)<2 ){
        echo "Your fi";
    }
}
```

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">

<input type = "text" name="reg_fname" placeholder="First Name"       required>
<br>
<input type = "text" name="reg_lname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
<br>
<input type = "email" name="reg_email" placeholder="Email" required>
<br>
<input type = "password" name="reg_pass" placeholder="Password" required>
<br>
<input type = "password" name="reg_pass2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
<br>
<input type = "submit" name="register_button" value="Register">

</form>
```

Comment: Are these inside a `<form>` element? What does `var_dump($_POST)` tell you?

Comment: Yes they are inside a <form> element. var_dump($_POST) returns array(6) { ["reg_fname"]=> string(1) "a" ["reg_lname"]=> string(3) "asd" ["reg_email"]=> string(5) "ad@ad" ["reg_pass"]=> string(4) "dasd" ["reg_pass2"]=> string(5) "sadsa" ["register_button"]=> string(8) "Register" } Invalid format

Comment: Edit your question to include this information

Comment: Properly indenting your code would help you find your problem. You're getting inside your first `if` statement just fine, but you're confused about where your `else` statement goes. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: Not to mention the missing quote in your SQL query and `strlen(fname)`. Please take the time to perform basic syntax checking before posting questions here.

Comment: Also you shouldn't silently alter users' passwords. If I want to have `my<pass>word` as a password I should be able to, no? And, last but not least, you should be using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for your database access.

Comment: DO NOT alter or filter passwords. It's unreasonable and you're making them vulnerable. Use the Password Hashing API to hash and validate passwords.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It is getting inside the first `if` statement.  You can tell because when you `var_dump($_POST)` you are getting the text "Invalid format" after the dump output.  That means it's getting into your `else` statement further down the page, where you have `echo "Invalid format";`.  So it's actually your `filter_var` `if` statement that is failing.

Comment: Problems that are the result of a typo such as a missing or extra `}` are not on-topic for SO. Instead of answering, flag the question for closure as off-topic.

Comment: This is not the result of a typo.  His code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

please don't edit your question after anyone answer 
You don't check if query successfully.
You used if to filter variable the best is make it directly
You forgot add comma in query after string .

please try the below

```
<?php
$fname = "";
$lname = "";
$em = "";
$em2 = "";
$password = "";
$password2 = "";
$date = "";
$error_array = "";
if (isset($_POST['register_button'])) {
    $fname = strip_tags($_POST['reg_fname']);
    $fname = str_replace(' ', ' ', $fname);
    $lname = $_POST['reg_lname'];
    $lname = str_replace(' ', ' ', $lname);

    $em = $_POST['reg_email'];
    $em = str_replace(' ', ' ', $em);

    $password = strip_tags($_POST['reg_pass']);
    $password2 = strip_tags($_POST['reg_pass2']);

    $date = date("Y-m-d");
    // No need to use if
    $em = filter_var($em, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    /// $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pass", "dbname");
    /// using if to be sure query success
    if ($e_check= mysqli_query($con, "SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$em'")) {

        $num_rows= mysqli_num_rows($e_check);
        if ($num_rows> 0) {
            echo "Email already in use";
        } else {
            /// here your insert query

        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "No query ";
    } 
    if(strlen($fname) >25 || strlen($fname)< 2 )
    { 
        echo "Your first name must be at least 2 char and maximum 25 char "; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use "register_button" as your check?  Why not one of your fields that is necessary?